# How to stop second $lookup to run on the first one's output?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

So I'm working on this project where I have a collection of posts which have fields like categories and authors. I need to fetch data based on certain categories and authors with the help of MongoDB's aggregate.

Right now in my aggregate object I have two `$lookups` one after the other and the second lookup is filtering data from the first one's output. So therefore I'm not getting all the data from the collection which matches with the second lookups criteria.

Suppose in my collection there are 10 categories and 10 authors. First I need to fetch all the posts with category name 'X' (collection has 5 Xs). So in the first lookup it should return 5 posts with X.

So in the same way I also need to fetch posts with author 'Y' (collection has 8 Ys). But right now it is returning all the Ys from the 5 Xs only. But I need to return all the posts from the collection which matches with Y, that is 8 of them.

Here's the aggregate obj:

```
const aggregateObj = [ 
        {
            '$lookup': {
                'from': 'categories', 
                'localField': 'categories.category', 
                'foreignField': '_id', 
                'as': 'categories'
            }
        }, 
        {
            '$match': {
                "categories.category": {
                    $in: [ 'X' ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            '$lookup': {
                'from': 'authors', 
                'localField': 'author', 
                'foreignField': '_id', 
                'as': 'author'
            }
        }, 
        {
            '$match': {
                "author.author": {
                    $in: [ 'Y' ]
                }
            }
        }
    ];

    const result = await Post
        .aggregate( aggregateObj )
        .exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might fit your need

```js
const aggregateObj = [ 
        {
            '$lookup': {
                'from': 'categories', 
                'localField': 'categories.category', 
                'foreignField': '_id', 
                'as': 'categories'
            }
        }, 
        {
            '$lookup': {
                'from': 'authors', 
                'localField': 'author', 
                'foreignField': '_id', 
                'as': 'author'
            }
        }, 
        {
            '$match': {
                $or: [
                   {
                      "categories.category": {
                         $in: [ 'X' ]
                      }
                   },
                   {
                      "author.author": {
                          $in: [ 'Y' ]
                      }                 
                   }
                ]
            }
        }
    ];
```